# Why push method in return statement throws error but concat works?

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me to understand why using `push` in return statement in following code is throwing error while `concat` work as expected.In both the case the accumulator is an array. If I separate `push` and `return` statement it works as expected.

```js
let flattened = [
  [0, 1],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5]
].reduceRight(function(a, b) {
  return a.push(b);
}, []);
console.log(flattened)
```

```js
let flattened = [
  [0, 1],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5]
].reduceRight(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);
console.log(flattened)
```

Comment: Because you can't push an array?

Comment: [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length. [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns the new array.

Comment: console.log(a.push(b)) Simple debugging

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.push` function adds new item and returns the new length of the array, not returning the new array with the added item.

So on the first snippet, after processing the first item, the accumulator will be set as the array length: `1`.

And `1.push` (Number.push) is not existed so it throws error.

But `Array.prototype.concat` is different.
It returns the new array concated so it works.

Answer (score 2):

`push` returns the new length of the array, when you return that from `reduce`/`reduceRight`, that length (a number) will be used in the next iteration as the accumulator `a`, since numbers don't have a method called `push`, the error is thrown.

`concat` works, however, because `concat` returns and array and arrays have a method called `push`.

If you want to use `push`, you'll have to first push the values then return the array like so:

```js
let flattened = [
  [0, 1],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5]
].reduceRight(function(a, b) {
  a.push(...b);                 // first, push the values you want. The spread syntax is used here because you want to push the items of 'b' not 'b' itself
  return a;                     // then return the array to be used as the accumulator for the next array
}, []);
console.log(flattened)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the two:

- [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds the element to the end of the array and returns the new length
- [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)  merge two or more arrays and returns a new array